# Xamarin Live Player setting BackgroundImage on Page throws ArgumentNullException

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

Ok so I have a `BasePage` class that inherits from `ContentPage`. All my other pages inherit from `BasePage`. In the `BasePage` constructor I simply change the `NavigationBar` icon (which works fine), but when I try to do `BackgroundImage = "default.png";` I get the following error in Xamarin Live Player: `Uncaught Exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: image (ArgumentNullException)`.

The image `default.png` is located in the `Resources` folder and its `BuildAction = BundleResource`. I can add any image in XAML or code-behind files except `BackgroundImage` is not working for me.

Tested the same code on a simulator and normal iPhone which builds through a Mac and both cases worked so it must be Xamarin Live Player. Any ideas as to how I might solve this?